# How can I kill all other terminals in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm wondering if anyone knows a command or hack to close all OTHER terminals besides the actively focused/selected one?

[image: kill others]

Kind of like the `Close Others` command for open file editors:
[image: close other file editors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made an extension to add such a command to the terminal tabs' context menu:

[Close other Terminals](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.close-other-terminals)

[image: Close other Terminals extension demo]

Let me know if it works for you.

It works for multiple terminal tab selections too.

It closes all the other editors other than the one(s) that are selected when you right-click on one of those.  You can right-click on any terminal tab - which may or may not be the currently active terminal.

You can use the `Close other Terminals` command from the Command Palette.

And you can create a keybinding to run the command (in your `keybindings.json`) like this:

```
{
  "key": "alt+k",
  "command": "close-other-terminals.close",
  
  "when": "terminalFocus"   // omit this to have it work in an editor
  // see below to use terminalFocus when clause 
}
```

If you want that `when` clause, make sure to add `close-other-terminals.close` to the following setting:

```
Terminal > Integrated: Commands to Skip Shell
```

Comment: Awsome, thanks Mark!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a thing. To substantiate, at the time of this writing (VS Code 1.84):

- searching "terminal kill" in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) doesn't show such a command
- triggering autocompletion in keybindings with "terminal.kill" in keybindings.json doesn't show such a command
- searching "terminal.kill" in the VS Code source code yields nothing more than can be found in command suggestions in keybindings.json
- googling "`github vscode issues kill all but active terminal`" yields nothing in the first page of results
- [searching `is:open is:issue label:terminal label:feature-request kill`  in the issues tab](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3Aterminal+label%3Afeature-request+kill) yields nothing

I'd suggest that you raise a feature-request issue ticket.

If/when you raise an issue ticket, be aware that there are nuances- terminals aren't constrained to tabs in the Terminal Panel- they can be moved into the editor area as editor tabs as well. There'll probably need to be some design discussion surrounding that.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.